# How to adjust visibility of UIBarButtonItem in Storyboard programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, storyboard

I have a UIBarButtonItem (defined in Storyboard), I've assigned to my own custom SwitchConsumerBarButton class.

What I want to do is dictate it's visibility on Page Init based on some criteria. I'd like to do this programmatic. I've tried implementing -(id) init but it doesn't get called, how do I control the initialization of this object? I've looked at the different initialization methods that can be called for this type, but I don't know which one the Storyboard will call?

```
@implementation SwitchBarButton

-(id) init
{
    if(self = [super init]) {
        NSLog(@"gwojbngowj");
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you mean to adjust the alpha, or to hide the button outright, so here's both.

```
if (myCondition == YES) {
    myButton.alpha = 0.5;
    //Or if you mean hide all together...
    [myButton setHidden:YES];
}
```

If you are looking to create the button depending on the variable, you could do that like this:

```
if (myCondition == YES) {
    UIBarButtonItem *myBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction target:self action:@selector(mySelector)];
    [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:myBarItem];
}
```

Comment: Where do I put that code? Init the viewDidLoad / initWithCoder ? I've tried both and its not displaying the button at all..

Comment: I'm using the second one, and removed the conditional, so it should be adding it to the navigation every time, but its not..., I Just want to it programmatically (regardless of the condition at this stage)

Comment: @Baconbeastnz Alright, does the app have a navigation controller, or did you just drag and drop the navigation bar in interface builder?

Comment: Oh, I just put a Navigation Item on it (drag and drop)

Comment: @Baconbeastnz Alright, then you're going to want to declare the bar in your header file as an outlet and link it in interface builder. Then instead of `self.navigationItem` you'll use the name of the bar you declared.

Comment: @Baconbeastnz glad to help, if my answer has solved your problem be sure to mark it as correct and up vote. I'd appreciate it a lot!

Comment: Didn't work for me at ALL. My UIBarButtonItem is a standard + button added to the Navigation bar in the storyboard. I have an outlet to it, and can enable/disable it programmatically, but I can't make it go away. setHidden apparently is not available for UIBarButtonItem. And I can't create it programmatically, then add or remove it from the navigation bar, because it's created in storyboard and I want to use the segue